# Toolbar for browser using C#.NET?

Tags: c#

I want to develop a browser toolbar in C#.net, which has to read a URL in a web page and open that URL in other tab or window.Please suggest whether it is possible or not.

Provide some articles related to this stuff.

Comment: You could try to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.Iam trying to implement it in Internet Explorer, in my client's web page there will one Image URL assigned to label or textbox.My toolbox need to access that URL value and open it in other tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, it is possible.](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)